# I only want to show images after anchors in the top level navigation

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navigation

When making a multi-level wordpress menu, I would like to use an image after the anchor tag (a simple dropdown arrow, but only on the top level. Simply using the "after" key in functions.php will make all my links have the image. How do I make it so only the top level has an image in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that menu structure is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a>Link</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Sub link</a></li>
        <li><a>Sub link</a></li>
        <li><a>Sub link</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

you can select top level `li` elemets by `.nav > li`. See how [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp) work. Then apply the image through css, it's better than `<img>`.

Comment: I would like to do it programatically rather than CSS